# POST method passing deserialized json as an empty string

Tags: java

I was searching for an answer, but I didn't find anything similar to my issue.

I have simple REST API, written as learning project and I have hard time creating proper POST method in controller. Other basic commands are working properly, just this one is making things tough.

### My code:

#### Controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/foo")
public class TaskController {

    private final DbService dbService;
    private final FooMapper fooMapper;

    @Autowired
    public FooController(DbService dbService, FooMapper fooMapper) {
        this.dbService = dbService;
        this.fooMapper = fooMapper;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/createFoo", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void createFoo(@RequestBody FooDto fooDto) {
         dbService.saveFoo(fooMapper.mapToFoo(FooDto));
    }
```

#### Repository:

```
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, Long> {

    @Override
    List<Foo> findAll();

    Optional<Foo> findByIdEquals(long fooId);

    @Override
    Foo save(Foo foo);

    @Override
    long count();

 }
```

#### Service:

```
@Service
public class DbService {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository repository;

    public List<Foo> getAllFoos() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    public Foo saveFoo(final Foo foo) {
        return repository.save(foo);
    }

    public Optional<Foo> getFoo(final long fooId) {
        return repository.findByIdEquals(fooId);
    }

    public void deleteFoo (final long FooId) {
        repository.deleteById(fooId);
    }
}
```

#### Testing above code with:

```
@Test
public void testShouldCreateTask() throws Exception {
    //Given
    FooDtofookDto = new FooDto(1L, "Title", "Content");
    Foo foo = new Foo(1L, "Title after", "Content after");

    when(dbService.saveFoo(foo)).thenReturn(foo);

    //When&&Then
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonContent = gson.toJson(fooDto);
    System.out.println(jsonContent);
    mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/foo/createFoo")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
            .content(jsonContent))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect((jsonPath("$.title", is("Title after"))));
}
```

#### gives this result:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /v1/foo/createFoo
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
             Body = {"id":1,"title":"Title","content":"Content"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.crud.foos.controller.FooController
           Method = public void    com.crud.foos.controller.FooController.createFoo(java.lang.String,com.crud.foos.domain.FooDto)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.title"
```

If I understand correctly the POST request is handled, but for some reason serialized object body is lost, thus I receive "no value" result, but status is 200. I was consulting numerous pages and sources, and I can't find an error in the provided code. If any extra information is helpful, I will provide it of course.

Comment: Well, your test expects the body of the response to be JSON, and to have a title property. But your controller method returns void. How could a `void` be transformed to a JSON object with a title property?

Comment: Well, as an excuse I can say that I was looking at this code for far too long. Thank you very much!